# What is the cardinality of the set of regular grammars?

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars, combinatorics

What is the cardinality of the set of regular grammars?  The caveat is that I'm only interested in grammars which are 'structurally' different.  Sorry I don't know how to talk about this in a formal way, but what I mean is that the actual symbols are arbitrary to me.

So for example the grammar with:
{N={α},
Σ={x},
P={α→x},
S=α}

Is equivalent to the grammar:
{N={β},
Σ={y},
P={β→y},
S=β}

Hopefully I am being understood!  I believe this set is countable because for every N and Σ there are only a finite number of production rules which can be formulated.  For example, for:

N={α} and 
Σ={x}

The only unique sets of production rules are:

{{α→x}}

{{α→xα}}

{{α→x}, {α→xα}}

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "structurally different", but I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is at least one regular grammar per regular language, and all of them are pairwise inequivalent (for any meaningful equivalence relation). Since there is at least a countably infinite number of regular languages¹, that's a lower bound for the number of regular grammars as well.

Without loss of generality², you can write down every regular grammar as finite string over a finite alphabet. Therefore, there are at most as many regular grammars as binary strings, of which there are countably infinitely many.

Combine the bounds to get your answer.

---

1. The lower bounds follows from $\{a\}^n$ being regular for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
2. Encode all symbols using binary numbers.